# Adding and comparing two decimal numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add two decimal numbers (arguments could be numbers or strings that are numbers before they are parsed) and compare the outcome with the `resultInput`. The problem is that the floating-point numbers cannot be represented accurately enough by the system. For example, `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004`. So, I am trying to use `toFixed()` method to format a number using fixed-point notation. I am getting `false` when I run the code. Not sure where I am getting it wrong. Let me know if you have any ideas.

```js
    function calc(firstNumber, secondNumber, operation, resultInput) {
      let a = parseFloat(firstNumber); //Number()
      let b = parseFloat(secondNumber); //Number()
      let c;
      let d = parseFloat(resultInput);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(`value of d : ${d}`)); //"value of d : NaN"
    
      switch (operation) {
        case '+':
          c = a + b;
          break;
        case '-':
          c = a - b;
          break;
        case '*':
          c = a * b;
          break;
        case '/':
         if (b === 0 && 1 / b === -Infinity) {
           r = Infinity;
         } else {
           r = a / b;
         }
          break;
        default:
          console.log(`Sorry, wrong operator: ${operation}.`);
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(`value of c: ${c}`)); // "value of c: 0.30000000000000004"
      let f = +c.toFixed(1);
      let e = +d.toFixed(1);
    
      console.log(JSON.stringify(`value of f: ${f}`)); // "value of f: 0.3"
      console.log(typeof f); //number
      console.log(JSON.stringify(`value of d: ${d}`)); // "value of d: NaN"
      console.log(typeof d); //number
      console.log(JSON.stringify(`value of e: ${e}`)); // "value of e: NaN"
      console.log(typeof e); //number
    
      if (f !== e) return false;
      // if (!Object.is(f, e)) return false;
      return true;
    }
    
    console.log(calc('0.1', '0.2', '+', '0.3'));
```

Comment: `.toFixed()` returns a string so you'll need to convert it back to a number. `let f = parseFloat(c.toFixed(1));`

Comment: this is what I want. To compare two strings `"0.3" === "0.3" //true`. or I am missing something?

Comment: Don't wrap numbers with quotes they become strings. Strings do not behave like numbers.

Comment: I need them to be strings as inputs. This is the condition of the task I am trying to solve.

Comment: Why bother using `parseFloat()`? Do you mean `<input>` tags? They should accept numbers and store them as strings.

Comment: cause the inputs could be numbers or strings. I am going to add this detail to the question.

Comment: You appear to have some invisible characters showing up in your `result` string. You may want to consider parsing and `.toFixed`ing `result` as well to ensure accuracy

Comment: @zer00ne inputs meaning the arguments. sorry for not being accurate.

Comment: @Hamms I updated the code in the question but now I am getting `NaN` when I parse the `result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run your code several times and there is no problem with it. I just found that the `'0.3'` that you posted, it has an special character that looks like `3` but its not `3`. So, when you want to run it on JS it will show an error. So your solution was correct. Check here.

```js
function calc(firstNumber, secondNumber, operation, resultInput) {
  let a = parseFloat(firstNumber);
  let b = parseFloat(secondNumber);
  let aux = parseFloat(resultInput);
  let r;

  switch (operation) {
    case '+':
      r = a + b;
      break;
    case '-':
      r = a - b;
      break;
    case '*':
      r = a * b;
      break;
    case '/':
      if (b !== 0) {
        r = a / b;
      } else {
        r = 0;
      }
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`Sorry, wrong operator: ${operation}.`);
  }

  return (+r.toFixed(1)) === (+aux.toFixed(1));
}

console.log(calc('0.1', '0.2', '+', '0.3'));
```

Comment: it returns `true` as it supposed .

Comment: I am still confused with this special character. But I will try to git into it. Thank you!

Comment: probably someone cracked a joke to you. In Cyrillic capital letter ze looks like 3 the unicode hexadecimal is 0x417

Comment: do you think it is possible that I have a malware hacking my keyboard  for numbers when I type?

Comment: Mhmm, I could be, just in case do a backup. format your PC and install a clean OS. I always have an image of a clean installation. So it only takes 20-35 mins to get a fresh and clean installation by restoring the image.

Comment: I found this character just after the number three Output (source encoding : KOI-7) `+ицВ-`
not sure what is the meaning of this

Comment: +ицВ- DOI? I also don't know the meaning of that sorry :'(

Answer (score 4):

Rather than converting back and forth to/from strings, you can create a function that tests if two numbers are close enough to be called equal. You decide some small delta and if the numbers are at least that close, you call it good.

```js
function almost(a, b, delta = 0.000001){
    return Math.abs(a - b) < delta
}

// not really equal
console.log("equal?", 0.2 + 0.1 === 0.3)

// but good enough
console.log("close enough?", almost(0.2 + 0.1, 0.3))
```

Comment: But can you please explain why this code is wrong ?

Comment: @Conan I just found that the '0.3' that I posted, it has an special character that looks like 3 but its not 3. The solution was correct.

Comment: @JohnJohn the three is fine it's character code 51 which is ascii 3. The string is surrounded by &#8236 and &#8237 which are non-printing control characters used in bidirectional text.

Comment: @MarkMeyer that is very odd , cause when I check my keybord characters in ASCII table it shows `Dec - 39 Hex-27 Binary-00100111 HTML-&#39; Char - ' Single quote`
https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not an direct answer, but an explanation about `toFixed()` and behavior of floating point numbers:

`toFixed()` returns a text. One reason is, that generally no number exists, the can represent the result of `toFixed()`. So use this function only for displaying, but not for calculating like here.

```
let f = +c.toFixed(1);
let e = +d.toFixed(1);
```

`toPrecision(18)` is good to display all relevant digits of a number. Some examples:

```
 (0.1).toPrecision(18) // => 0.100000000000000006
 (0.2).toPrecision(18) // => 0.200000000000000011
 (0.3).toPrecision(18) // => 0.299999999999999989
```

The examples explains, why `0.1+0.2` is not the same as `0.3`.

Same examples with `toFixed(1)`:

```
(+(0.1).toFixed(1)).toPrecision(18) // => 0.100000000000000006
(+(0.2).toFixed(1)).toPrecision(18) // => 0.200000000000000011
(+(0.3).toFixed(1)).toPrecision(18) // => 0.299999999999999989
```

It changed nothing: `toFixed(1)` formats the number, and the `+` sign convert it back to the nearest existing number.

This is not a JavaScript issue, it is an issue of computer based floating points number using IEEE 754 (binary based numbers). Most hardware support this kind of floats.

In computer mathematics it is usual, to compare equality of floating point numbers by using absolute or relative delta values. Example for absolute delta:

```
function isEqual( num1, num2, epsilon )
{
    return Math.abs( num1 - num2 ) <= epsilon;
}

isEqual( 0.1 + 0.2, 0.3, 1e-10 ) // => true
```

Databases support dataytpes like `DECIMAL(5.1)`. Here `0.1+0.2 == 0.3`, because the use internally interger numbers and format only the output.

JavaScript example for currency with 2 fraction digits (euro,cent):

```
// scan user input:
cent = round( euro * 100 );

// adding cents:
cent3 = cent1 + cent2;

// print cents as euro
(cent/100).toFixed(2)+"€"
```

Comment: He is not using `toFixed()` to calculate anything, he is comparing the operation result with the desired result. So you are making the solution more complex by adding multiple conversions just compare two elements. The problem is simple, I have a number and I need to compare it with another element that can be either a number or a string.